# Syntax error when webpack build for development

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, webpack

I can't build a project with webpack because I'm getting a syntax error all the time.
Moreover when my friend runs the same code on Linux (I work on Windows 10) he doesn't get any errors and everything works fine.

Here is my webpack config

```js
const path = require('path');

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');

const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const HMRPlugin = require('webpack/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
const OccurrenceOrderPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/OccurrenceOrderPlugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

//=========================================================
//  VARS
//---------------------------------------------------------
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const DEVELOPMENT = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const PRODUCTION = NODE_ENV === 'production';

const HOST = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || '3000';

//=========================================================
//  LOADERS
//---------------------------------------------------------
const rules = {
    js: {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
    },

    json: {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
    },

    css: {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        }),
    },

    scss: {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        }),
    },

    fonts: {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
            name: `[name].[ext]`,
            publicPath: '/assets/fonts/',
        }
    },

    images: {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: `[name].[ext]`,
            publicPath: '/assets/images/',
        }
    }
};

//=========================================================
//  CONFIG
//---------------------------------------------------------
const config = {};

config.entry = {
    polyfills: './src/application/polyfills.js',
    main: ['./src/application/index.js'],
};

config.output = {
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    // publicPath: '/',
};

config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    modules: [
        path.resolve('./src'),
        'node_modules',
    ]
};

config.module = {
    rules: [
        rules.js,
        rules.css,
        rules.json,
        rules.scss,
        rules.fonts,
        rules.images,
    ]
};

config.plugins = [
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: !PRODUCTION,
        cache: !PRODUCTION,
        minimize: PRODUCTION,
        options: {
            postcss: [
                autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
                })
            ],
            sassLoader: {
                outputStyle: PRODUCTION ? 'compressed' : 'expanded',
                precision: 10,
                sourceComments: false,
                sourceMap: PRODUCTION,
            }
        }
    }),
    new DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
    }),
    new OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'polyfills',
        chunks: ['polyfills'],
    }),
    // This enables tree shaking of the vendors modules
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: ['main'],
        minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource),
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse(),
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: './src/assets',
            to: 'assets',
            ignore: ['**/*.scss'],
        }
    ]),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'assets/css/[name].css',
        disable: !PRODUCTION,
        allChunks: true,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: false,
        inject: 'body',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        template: './src/index.html',
    })
];


//=====================================
//  DEVELOPMENT
//-------------------------------------

if (DEVELOPMENT) {
    config.devtool = 'cheap-module-source-map';

    config.entry.main.unshift(
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    );

    config.plugins.push(
        new HMRPlugin(),
        new ProgressPlugin(),
    );

    config.devServer = {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: HOST,
        hot: true,
        port: PORT,
        stats: {
            cached: true,
            cachedAssets: true,
            children: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false,
            colors: true,
            modules: false,
            hash: false,
            reasons: true,
            timings: true,
            version: false,
        }
    };
}


//=====================================
//  PRODUCTION
//-------------------------------------
if (PRODUCTION) {
    config.devtool = 'hidden-source-map';

    config.plugins.push(
        new WebpackMd5Hash(),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            comments: false,
            compress: {
                unused: true,
                dead_code: true,
                screw_ie8: true,
                warnings: false,
            },
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
            }
        })
    );
}

module.exports = config;
```

And this is my package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "server:dev": "set NODE_ENV='development' && webpack-dev-server --color",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "build": "set NODE_ENV='production' && webpack --color"
  },
```

When I try to run "npm start", I have this error

```js
C:\Users\vellgreen\Desktop\my_webpack_react\webpack.config.js:184
        );
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

when I put this into comment everything is working normal.

```js
config.entry.main.unshift(
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    );

    config.plugins.push(
        new HMRPlugin(),
        new ProgressPlugin(),
    );
```

When I run code for production everything is also fine.
My OS is Windows 10, webpack v3.1.0, npm v5.3.0, node v6.10.3.

Does anyone know what may cause such an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing commas in functions are a relatively recent feature and Node started supporting it in [version 8](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-trailing-commas-in-function-syntax). Your friend is simply using a version that supports it (it's unrelated to the OS).

```
config.entry.main.unshift(
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
//                               ^ --- remove this comma
);

config.plugins.push(
    new HMRPlugin(),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
//                      ^ --- and this comma
);
```

Comment: Works! Thank you a lot for the answer and explanations!